# Create a page for every data file?

Tags: jekyll

I'm trying to build a jekyll site that can generate a page for every data file.

Say we have

```
/_data/
  a.yaml
  b.yaml
```

where
`a.yaml` has

```
event_name: A
time: yesterday
contents:
  - name: A1
    url: a1
  - name: B1
    url: b1
```

`b.yaml` is basically the same thing with different contents.

I would like the rendered site to have 2 pages: `/a.html` and `/b.html`. The contents of each page is a simple listing of the contents in `a.yaml` or `b.yaml`. Is it possible in current Jekyll?

I know there is a very nice jekyll addin called [jekyll-datapage-gen](https://github.com/avillafiorita/jekyll-datapage_gen). However, that addin generates pages for every item in a data file and is different from what I'm looking for... Can anyone provide some suggestions here? Thank you!

Comment: I would store the yaml in front matter in a .md file (so not in a yml file in the _data directory). But that might not be possible in your situation (given your question).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve that using Collections instead of data files.  Files will look the same, with front matter, and then you specify in the configuration to make each file a different late with `output: true`

Have a look at https://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/, your configuration will look like:

```
collections: 
    my_collection:
         output: true
```

It is possible to make the same with data files, creating the post a and the post b, and iterating in each page one of the data files, anyway I think using collections fits perfectly in this case.

Comment: So I guess I should rename those yaml files as .md, as @JoostS suggested?

Comment: @Hao yes, rename those guys to a.md for example and put the attributes/values between --- ---. Then create a directory with an underscore at the beginning as in the previous example, e.g.: _my_collection